# how to sum value to span

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am a beginner in JS and Jquery and cant find a solution to my task.

My goal is - whenever button with class='add-gold' clicked i want to add 20 to span with class='gold-vault'.
And when button with class='spend-gold' clicked subtract 20 from the same span

```html
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
      <button class='add-gold'> Add Gold</button>
      <button class='spend-gold'> Spend Gold</button>
      <span class='gold-storage'>0</span>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Did you do anything yet?

Comment: You're clearly just a beginner so I wanted to show you something cool that you'll learn some time in the future: https://jsfiddle.net/oj94aggf/

Comment: Of course I'd recommend that you start learning that now as well :P

Comment: Thank you Philter. I got the basics of JS and Jquery at Codecademy, but don't know where to go forward from now on.

Comment: Keep it up, buddy! I made some changes to my example: https://jsfiddle.net/evL9pzwx/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this :

```js
var $span = $(".gold-storage");

$(".add-gold").on("click", function() {
  var current = parseInt($span.html());
  
  $span.html(current + 20);
});

$(".spend-gold").on("click", function() {
  var current = parseInt($span.html());
  
  $span.html(current - 20);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
      <button class='add-gold'> Add Gold</button>
      <button class='spend-gold'> Spend Gold</button>
      <span class='gold-storage'>0</span>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Edit :

- If you want to keep your Gold in positif (min gold = 0), change `$span.html(current - 20);` by `if (current > 0) { $span.html(current - 20); }` so you won't remove gold if gold is not > 0 (min gold to remove is 20 here)
- If you want to make ONE trigger event : instead of `$(".add-gold").on("click", function() { ... }` and `$(".spend-gold").on("click", function() { ... }` you can do `$("button").on("click", function() { ... }` and to know if you have to add or remove gold, check the button class : `if ($(this).hasClass('add-gold'))`(return true or false, with $(this) the button you click on).

Is it what you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Added a check so you cant have negative gold

```js
var gold = 0;
      $(".add-gold").click(function(){
        gold = +gold + 20;
        $(".gold-storage").text(gold)
      });
      $(".spend-gold").click(function(){
        if (gold >= 20){
        gold = +gold - 20;
        $(".gold-storage").text(gold)
        }        
      });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class='add-gold'> Add Gold</button>
      <button class='spend-gold'> Spend Gold</button>
      <span class='gold-storage'>0</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution for your question.

```js
$('.add-gold').click(function(){
    var currentstock = parseInt($('.gold-storage').text());
    $('.gold-storage').text(currentstock + 20);
});

$('.spend-gold').click(function(){
    var currentstock = parseInt($('.gold-storage').text());
    $('.gold-storage').text(currentstock - 20);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
      <button class='add-gold'> Add Gold</button>
      <button class='spend-gold'> Spend Gold</button>
      <span class='gold-storage'>0</span>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here. I didn't use jQuery as I don't know if you can or want to use it.

Besides, this changes even if the span is empty, and you never get negative values for gold

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var gold = document.querySelector('.gold-storage');

  function changeGold(quantity) {
    var current = parseInt(gold.textContent);
    var newGold = isNaN(current) ? quantity : current + quantity;
    if (newGold < 0) {
      newGold = 0;
    }
    gold.innerHTML = newGold;
  }

  document.querySelector('.add-gold').addEventListener('click', function() {
    changeGold(20)
  });

  document.querySelector('.spend-gold').addEventListener('click', function() {
    changeGold(-20)
  });
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
      <button class='add-gold'> Add Gold</button>
      <button class='spend-gold'> Spend Gold</button>
      <span class='gold-storage'>0</span>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

First you can  turn the span text into a number so you can add/subtract numbers to/from it.

Then you use conditionals to see which button is clicked so you know if you add or sutract.

Hope it helps

```js
let button = $("button")


button.on("click", function() {
  let number = parseInt($(".gold-storage").text(), 10);
  if ($(this).hasClass("add-gold")) {

    $(".gold-storage").text(number + 20);
  }
  if ($(this).hasClass("spend-gold")) {
    $(".gold-storage").text(number - 20);

  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class='add-gold'> Add Gold</button>
<button class='spend-gold'> Spend Gold</button>
<span class='gold-storage'>0</span>
```

Comment: I like this one due to the radix.